# PHPUnit file generation and test specific options

Tags: php, automated-tests, phpunit, mpdf

I have a `TestPdfGeneration.php` file that, well, generates a PDF file as output through MPDF.

Due (I think) to how MPDF behaves, I should add the `--stderr` option when running that test, otherwise it complains about "headers already been sent"; I've checked the PHPUnit docs, but there's no mention of how to add options "on the fly" to a specific test file.

I could add the option in the `phpunit.xml` file, but that would be applied globally; what I'm looking for is a way to add that option to only those test classes that actually need it.

Can anyone help me?

**Edit**

Here is how I generate the PDF file: it uses a wrapper-package for mPDF in order to use it with Laravel. The `mPDF` object itself can be obtained using the `getMpdf()` function.

```
$pdf_config = [
      'tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/tempPdf',
      'format' => 'A4',
      'setAutoTopMargin' => 'pad',
      'margin_top' => 5,
      'margin_footer' => 5,
    ];

    $pdf = PDF::getPdf($pdf_config);

    if(isset($pdf_data['bozza'])) {
      $pdf->getMpdf()->SetWatermarkText('DRAFT');
      $pdf->getMpdf()->showWatermarkText = true;
    }

    $pdf->getMpdf()->setAutoTopMargin = 'pad';
    $pdf->getMpdf()->shrink_tables_to_fit = 1;
    $pdf->getMpdf()->WriteHTML(View::make($pdf_data['view'], $pdf_data, [])->render());

    // D -> Download
    // I -> Inline => stream
    return $pdf->getMpdf()->Output($pdf_data['filename'], 'I');
```

I think the main point is the `WriteHTML` function in mPDF, cause that's when the render function for the view is called.

Comment: Can you share how do you generate the PDF? There certainly is a way for mPDF not to check headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `S` as a mode for generating PDF. It does not send HTTP headers like `I` does, it just returns binary PDF string.

```
return $pdf->getMpdf()->Output($pdf_data['filename'], 'S');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There's a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73718077/phpunit-set-up-test-for-file-generation), if you wish to help me further.