# PHPUnit set up test for file generation

Tags: php, pdf, testing, phpunit, software-design

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73459900/1785967) question, I struggle to find the correct approach to create tests for a situation like this:

1. different entry points in the application lead to generate some kind of PDF file (for sake of example, one could be `/pdf/report` and the other `/pdf/details`);
2. each entry point calls a specific function in the `PDFController`, where it gathers the data to be placed in the PDF file (let's call the functions `report` and `details`);
3. both functions, internally, call the same `PDFService` class (specifically, a `function outputPDF($pdf_data)` to generate the file to be sent back to the client.

   Inside this function there's the call mentioned in the other question, in particular the line `$pdf->getMpdf()->Output($pdf_data['filename'], 'D');`

The question is: how do I set up a feature test to check the `/pdf/report` and `/pdf/details` entry points?

As answered in the other question, I should change the `'D'` format with `'S'` in order to avoid the header to be sent beforehand, but that would change the actual behaviour of the software, where I want those PDF files to be downloaded.

Even passing the "output format" as a parameter to the `outputPDF` function (`function outputPDF($pdf_data, $output_format)`) sounds wrong, given it's just for the testing phase.

I think I'm missing something, here...

Comment: Are you using any framework? Testing entire controllers is solved in plenty of them already - basically you fake the request and assert conditions against the HTTP response - including the response code and additional headers. https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/17-tests.html#writing-functional-tests-for-controllers

Comment: Laravel 5.5. Yes, I know it's not the latest version, and yes, I am working on upgrading it (these tests I'm making go towards that).

Comment: Yes, even Laravel can do that https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/http-tests